# C++ error C2065 undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm a bit confused. I want to be able to display the carMake by using the vehicle type. If I use an if statement using the year, I get the carMake like I want. I can't get the if (vehicleType == CAR) to work for me. Please help. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string vin, carMake, carModel, vehicleType;
    int year, weight;
    ofstream fout;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open ("VehicleInput.txt");
    fout.open("VehicleOutput.txt");   
    fout << "Vehicle Registration Information" << endl;

    while(!fin.eof())
    {

        fin >> vin;
        fin >> carMake;
        fin >> carModel;
        fin >> year;
        fin >> vehicleType;
        fin >> weight; 

        if (vehicleType == CAR)     //If I use if (year == 2007) it will spit out the carMake.
        { 
            cout << carMake << endl;
        }

    }
    fin.close();    
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about to use "CAR" instead of CAR?

Comment: also change your while loop condition `while (!fin.eof())` is not the way to do it, write instead `while (fin >> vin) { ... }` .eof() is triggered when you read *past* end of file not when you read last string in file.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
if (vehicleType == "CAR")
{ 
    cout << carMake << endl;
}
```

By writing CAR without quotes, you don't compare vehicleType to the string "CAR" but to a variable or something else named CAR.

Answer (score 0):

vehicleType is variable of string type so it can be compared to some string (like vehicleType=="CAR") or you can consider other available string comparisioon functions.